# how to find maximum KAFKA topic size consumed over a time frame

Tags: apache-kafka

I am looking for some options to find the maximum size a kafka topic ever used over a timeframe. My application uses a topic sized 100GB, i often feel it is under utilized so want to reduce the size however i want to first monitor the usage, the max size it ever reached at topic level not at broker level. This will help me size the topic appropriately leaving some buffer size on top of max.
Any such admin UI or a script that helps me achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

> at topic level not at broker level

This isn't really possible without aggregating partition sizes, on disk, at the broker level.

There is no Kafka specific API for this, other than `kafka-log-dirs` CLI. Otherwise, I would recommend some tool that can export directory usage to Prometheus, where you can aggregate and visualize over time usage.

> 100GB... feel it is under utilized

Unclear what this means, as it depends entirely on your producer and topic retention settings. If you want less storage, lower the retention time. Also, if you have 3 replicas of that topic, it's actually 300GB in size once fully replicated.